# Regex to remove double-quotes in CSV fields that are delineated by double-quotes

Tags: regex, vb.net, csv

This is for a VB.NET project. My existing method converts a comma-delimited file to a pipe-delimited file. It got a little challenging because some of the fields had commas within them, so those fields had double-quotes around the fields contents.

Here's the working code (thanks a million to The Blue Dog for the research on this):

```
Private Function ConvertCommaSepToPipeSep() As Boolean
    Dim line, result As String
    Dim pattern As String = ",([^,""]*(?:""[^""]*"")?[^,""]*)(?=,|$)"
    Dim replacement As String = "|$1"
    Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)

    'Console.WriteLine("Conversion start time: " & DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString())
    Try
        Using sw As New StreamWriter("output.csv")
            Using sr As New StreamReader("source.csv")
                While Not sr.EndOfStream
                    line = sr.ReadLine
                    result = rgx.Replace(line, replacement)
                    sw.WriteLine(result.Replace(Chr(34), ""))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("There was a problem converting the file." & vbcrlf & ex.message)
        Return False
    End Try

    'Console.WriteLine("Conversion end time: " & DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString())
    Return True
End Function
```

I found out, however, that some of the fields have double-quotes within them as well.

Here are some sample lines from the source file that I am converting.

```
122749,JOHN DOE,ACS155,7/5/2014,P,SCH/RC Activation Week 2,HRLY,1299577,Scheduler IT,2204,CVISA-Client Activation,1220000,Svcs Clin Implement,34
110310,JANE DOE,ACS150,2/8/2014,P,"Developed Employee Interface""",HRLY,1267305,Project Management - Client Implementation Services,2500,PJM  -Project Management,1410000,Tech Services Development,8
110310,MARY DOE,ACS160,2/8/2014,P,EDManage+ CSV data extract,HRLY,1527401,Project Management - Client Implementation Services,2500,PJM  -Project Management,1410000,Tech Services Development,8
129084,ROBERT SMITH,ACS80,9/27/2014,P,,PTO,0,Company General Services,1030,"Time Off - PTO, Holiday, Personal Holiday, FTO",1100000,Client Services Technical,40
117592,HARRY JOHNSON,ACS64,5/10/2014,P,"helped penny post AP ""E"" cks",HRLY,1554404,General Financials IT,2120,CCON-Client Conference Call,1100000,Client Services Technical,1.5
110310,MARK WILSON,ACS130,2/8/2014,P,"""Charge Vs Payment""",HRLY,1267305,Project Management - Clinical Implementation Services,2500,PJM  -Project Management,1410000,Tech Services Development,8
```

Those same rows need to be converted to look like this:

```
122749|JOHN DOE|ACS155|7/5/2014|P|SCH/RC Activation Week 2|HRLY|1299577|Scheduler IT|2204|CVISA-Client Activation|1220000|Svcs Clin Implement|34
110310|JANE DOE|ACS150|2/8/2014|P|Developed Employee Interface""|HRLY|1267305|Project Management - Client Implementation Services|2500|PJM  -Project Management|1410000|Tech Services Development|8
110310|MARY DOE|ACS160|2/8/2014|P|EDManage+ CSV data extract|HRLY|1527401|Project Management - Client Implementation Services|2500|PJM  -Project Management|1410000|Tech Services Development|8
129084|ROBERT SMITH|ACS80|9/27/2014|P||PTO|0|Company General Services|1030|Time Off - PTO, Holiday, Personal Holiday, FTO|1100000|Client Services Technical|40
117592|HARRY JOHNSON|ACS64|5/10/2014|P|helped penny post AP E cks|HRLY|1554404|General Financials IT|2120|CCON-Client Conference Call|1100000|Client Services Technical|1.5
110310|MARK WILSON|ACS130|2/8/2014|P|Charge Vs Payment|HRLY|1267305|Project Management - Clinical Implementation Services|2500|PJM  -Project Management|1410000|Tech Services Development|8
```

In this CSV, columns that have commas in the text are given double-quotes around the column and the regex above accounts for that. But I found out that some fields also have double-quotes within them. Any instances of double-quotes within a field can be removed, but in some cases the field can end or start with a double quote, resulting in three double-quotes, but I can't just remove all double-quotes because they help delineate where fields that have commas in them start and end.

What needs to be added to the regex to do that?

Comment: As they should always be balanced how about just replacing `""` with nothing? This would leave an empty, unquoted field or a field with a single set or quotes.

Comment: The `""` are supposed to be converted to a single `"`. Are you sure you want to remove them completely?

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, you're right, they should be balanced. And scanning through the file, it looks like that's the case. How would that be added to the existing regex, then?

Comment: Can't you just `csvString = csvString.Replace( ... )` before you run the RE

Comment: @AlexK. I've been working on this so long, I'm missing the obvious. That did it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `""` are supposed to be converted to a single `"`. Are you sure you want to remove them completely?
                    – nhahtdh

Can't you just `csvString = csvString.Replace( ... )` before you run the RE
                    – Alex K.